# Redirect FILE * stream into custom handler in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qdebug

I would like to integrate a C library into my C++/Qt project. The library accepts a FILE* stream in order to print debug messages (rather than providing a hook for a logging callback function...).

It works properly if I just pass `stderr`, but I would like to integrate this into my own logging infrastructure, which uses `qDebug()` and co.

My initial idea was to use `socketpair()`, get the FILE* stream of the sending side's fd, pass it to the library, and handle the receiving side with QSocketNotifier, but I hit 2 issues with it:

- It's not multiplatform, although there are implementations for Windows.
- My application is single-threaded (and I want to keep it that way), and this means that the socketpair's 2 sockets are written and read from the same thread. This seems to be ending up with a deadlock after a while.

What are other methods existing to provide a FILE* stream, integrate its reading into Qt's event loop, doesn't require multiple threads, and is multiplatform?

Comment: Is it a public C library? If yes, which one? Maybe you can modify it quite easily.

Comment: Calling C functions from C++ does not qualify for a C-tag.

Comment: @Holt, libgps from gpsd, i could patch it, but it's a last option (assume i want to distribute the program, and i don't want to ship a modified lib with it). I'll consider to send a patch to the project.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can get a file descriptor to your storage, you can get `FILE*` from it using unportable `fdopen` on Linux and `_fdopen` on Windows.

You can also create a regular pipe both on Linux and Windows, using `pipe`/`_pipe`.

And a pipe should integrate with Qt event loop. I am not familiar with Qt APIs, may be it exposes portable APIs for that. May be you can use [QLocalSocket Class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocalsocket.html):

> The QLocalSocket class provides a local socket. On Windows this is a named pipe and on Unix this is a local domain socket.

It has `qintptr QLocalSocket::socketDescriptor() const` method that returns the file descriptor that can be wrapped with `fdopen` to make a `FILE*`.

Comment: [Calling Qt functions from Unix signal handlers](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html) give useful advice related to the "pipe to self"  trick

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch That example could just use one pipe for all signals writing `signo` into it, rather than a `socketpair` for each passing no useful data.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, i want to tweak the messages (prefix it with timestamp, tag like [DGB], etc), so directly giving access to the storage not an option. I'm going to try pipe(), thx.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, yes, i know this, but it uses socketpair() which i mentioned in my question.